# Scale profile picture to fit

Tags: image, resize, scale, profile, pixel

my logo will not fit into the profile picture on Facebook.  I have changed the pixels and it still does not work, tried to make it smaller, then Facebook says its too small, tried making it bigger, tried many different sizes and have spent way too much time in photo editing programs and it still does not work.  The logo is cut off in the square even when I reposition it and click scale to fit. Is there a simple solution?

Comment: You may want to read this: http://ustandout.com/facebook/size-facebook-profile-picture-thumbnail

Comment: I'm sorry,  This is a perfectly valid question, but on the wrong site.  This site is geared to programming questions for software developers.  IMage manipulation of the type you're asking about it not a programming task.  Voting to close as off-topic.